# Feature IDs table to Turn Feature Class in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, network-analyst, turns

I have a table of around 7,000 records that represents the restricted turns (illegal turns) in a city, and it looks like this:

[image]

The IDs in the table correspond to the Feature IDs in my streets layer involved in the restriction (for example, the first row represent an illegal turn involving 5 line features in that particular order).

Since, I'm using network analysis in ArcGIS 10.2.2 (Advanced License) to solve a Vehicle Routing problem, is there any quick way to build a Turn Feature Class including these 7,000 records without having to draw each one of them?

Comment: What have you tried so far and didn't work? I don't see why a join or a query layer would not work.

Comment: @MaryBeth, I haven't tried anything because I don't know if it's possible. Since the Turn Feature Class requires attributes such as Edge1End, Edge1FCID, Edge1FID, Edge1Pos, Edge2FCID, Edge2FID, Edge2Pos, Edge3FCID, Edge3FID, Edge3Pos, etc., I don't know how to generate them automatically or if there's another simpler way.